# Can I use pthreads over the same function on C?

Tags: c, function, pthreads

I have a doubt that might be silly guys. I am having a function to calculate some mathematical formulas as an example.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <math.h>


pthread_mutex_t a_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
volatile long int a = 0;


void threadOne(void *arg) 
{


 int i;
    long int localA = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < 50000000; i++) 
    {
     localA = localA + i*a*sqrt(a);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
    a = a + localA;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
}


void threadTwo(void *arg) 
{
    int i;
    long int localA = 0;
    for (i = 50000000; i <= 100000000; i++)
    {
     localA = localA + i*a*sqrt(a);
    }
   pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
   a = a + localA;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    pthread_t one, two;
    int i;
    pthread_create(&one, NULL, (void*)&threadOne, NULL);
    pthread_create(&two, NULL, (void*)&threadTwo, NULL);
    pthread_join(one, NULL);
    pthread_join(two, NULL);
}
```

Now this is an example I found, I am having two functions with a thread each one, so one is calculated on a different thread. But can I have just one function and then have two threads to one function, so the function runs twice with different data?. My idea is this one: I am having just one function that can have two different sets of data, then the function can run with the first set or the second set depending on the thread is running.

But is this possible even?. I want to avoid something as copying the function twice as here.

Lets use say that I only keep the function

```
void threadOne(void *arg)
```

But I run it twice using different threads at same time with different data, this can be achieved or I am just being silly?.

Comment: Yes. You only need mutual exclusion for data that's modified, code and read-only data can be shared just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I was coding and have this doubt about it. Thank you very much!, I am just starting with pthreads and has been quite a new thing :). Thank you again Barmar!.

Comment: Sure. The pthread API gives you a `void*` to pass data into the thread function. You can put a `struct *` into there and cast it back to the struct pointer in the function. That can have all the work data or pointers to a global work array. You could divide 100 million elements in one big array by the number of threads for example, and pass the start and end elements into each thread.

Comment: Just make sure that the thread arguments are allocated one for each thread. Don't try to reuse the same one to create many threads with. Somehow I see people make that mistake a lot. Also make sure the thread arguments live as long as the threads. Don't make the mistake of declaring an array of 10 arg structures for 10 threads in the function, create the threads, and exit the function. Because then every thread is pointing to unallocated stack memory.

Comment: Indentation makes your code readable...

Comment: ;) better now? <3

Comment: If you properly lock a mutex before using your `a` variable, it does not need to be volatile. It will not help.

Comment: gonna check that too, to be honest I am entering in to this :3. Gonna be back tomorrow with the comments of what happened guys!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by making use of the argument to the thread function.

Each thread needs to loop over a range of values.  So create a struct definition to contain the min and max values:

```
struct args {
    int min;
    int max;
};
```

Define a single thread function which converts the `void *` argument to a pointer to this type and reads it:

```
void *thread_func(void *arg) 
{
    struct args *myargs = arg;
    int i;
    long int localA = 0;
    for (i = myargs->min; i < myargs->max; i++) 
    {
        localA = localA + i*a*sqrt(a);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
    a = a + localA;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
    return NULL;
}
```

(Note that the function needs to return a `void *` to conform to the interface `pthread_create` expects.)

Then in your `main` function create an instance of this struct for each set of arguments, and pass that to `pthread_create`:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    pthread_t one, two;
    struct args args1 = { 1, 50000000 };
    struct args args2 = { 50000000 , 100000000 };
    pthread_create(&one, NULL, thread_func, &args1);
    pthread_create(&two, NULL, thread_func, &args2);
    pthread_join(one, NULL);
    pthread_join(two, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Gonna try it tomorrow morning, but will come back to tell ;)!.

Comment: Thank you, it worked flawlessly :). Would need to re-arrange my data and so but it was awesome :D